# Ruby - Iterating over xml elements with same name but distinct meaning using NokoGiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am using the UPS API to validate locations.  I receive the XML response from UPS then try to parse out the information I need.  UPS can send back one to three `<AddressLine>` elements per address, depending on the address.

If an address has two or more `AddressLines`, I need to pull out the first two.  If an address has only one `AddressLine`, I need to pull that one line.

How can I pull out address and address2?

```
<AddressKeyFormat>
  <AddressLine>655 MANSELL RD</AddressLine>
  <AddressLine>Apartment #2</AddressLine>
</AddressKeyFormat>
```

The code :

```
xml.xpath('//AddressKeyFormat').each do |node|
  #pull out address, and address2
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Collect or count the lines and decide what to do based on the count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `xml` is a Nokogiri XML document (e.g. `xml = Nokogiri::XML(xmlString)`) you can do an XPath search for `//AddressLine` and the result will be all of those nodes:

```ruby
xml.xpath('//AddressLine').map(&:text) # => ["655 MANSELL RD", "Apartment #2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a maximum of two addresslines:

```
xml.xpath('//AddressKeyFormat/AddressLine').map(&:text)[0,2]
```